# getting error : No space left on device in aws server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i created instance one month ago, it was working fine, but suddenly it stopped working, its strange, when i logged in with ssh, i used command `df -h`, i can some of that process are showing 100%, looks like cause of that i am getting that issue : `No space left on device`, i tried attach volume, but still it is not working, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ? here i have attacked my process

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           787M   80M  707M  11% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1  7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       29M   29M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2012
/dev/loop1       97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9436
/dev/loop2       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1566
/dev/loop3       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9289
tmpfs           787M     0  787M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Have you check [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html) on extending the portion after increasing size of your ebs volume?

Comment: yes i can see it in instance block devices

Comment: Your root partition is only `7.7G` which is already full. You can resize the volume to new size (e.g. 30GB) and than extend the linux partition as shown in the docs to use the new size.

Comment: new volume size is added of 100GB

Comment: Yes, but the problem is with existing root partition of 7.7GB. If you don't want to change it, then copy files that take up the space to the new volume and change application settings which generates these files. Maybe some logs, or cache is taking the space?

Comment: If it is Amazon Linux 2, then rebooting should expand the partition to use the new root volume size.

Comment: i am using aws ubuntu 18.04 instance, should i try reboot ?

Comment: Sure, give it a try. I remember that there is a `resize2fs` command that is executed automatically for the root volume upon booting an Amazon Linux AMI. It might be present for Ubuntu. If not, you would need to run it yourself to expand the partition to the new size of the volume. (Do some web searches to find the syntax.)

Answer (score 5):

First of all dont panic. It can be easily solved.

Steps

1. use the following command to see the memory status of your machine
   `df-h` 
   This will  dosplay the list of mounted volume on file system

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            992M     0  992M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M   21M  180M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1       7.7G   7.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000
```

You can see that `/dev/xvda1` is full.

2. To peek in `/dev/xvda1` further issue following command
   `sudo du -shx /* | sort -h`

```
This will hive the folderwise memory consumed like
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /srv
16K /lost+found
16K /opt
24K /snap
32K /tmp
532K    /home
7.0M    /etc
14M /sbin
16M /bin
42M /run
76M /boot
186M    /lib
195M    /root
2.2G    /usr
5.1G    /var
```

we can see that `/usr`  and `/var`  are consuming highest memory.

3. just drill down in these folders and remove unnecessary files
4. Go in aws ec2 instance and reboot it.
   Problem solved.